# Up arrow/history not working in R Console in Intellij

Tags: r, intellij-idea

As shown in the screenshot I have entered some commands in the `R` console - but how can the history be accessed?

Here is the page for the plugin:

http://holgerbrandl.github.io/r4intellij/#interactive-console

It does not list any way to do so.

[image]